# Open MPI: Get CPU and communication usage

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, openmpi, usage-statistics

Just a simple question:

I need to examine two things while using Open MPI:

- cpu usage
- communication usage

during MPI app running time. I found a few thing but I'm looking for new ideas already.

What i mean with -communication usage-: I want to know more about the messages between the ranks in e.g. number of messages, size in bytes and/or "band width" when/while MPI_Recv respectively MPI_Send occurs.

Is there a "simple" way to get these informations?

Greetings

Comment: If you search for "MPI Profiling" you'll find many tools from high-level summaries (  [mpiP](http://mpip.sourceforge.net/#mpiP_Output), [IPM](http://ipm-hpc.sourceforge.net/),  [OTF profiler](http://tu-dresden.de/die_tu_dresden/zentrale_einrichtungen/zih/forschung/projekte/otf) ) to much more in-depth performance tools like [Scalasca](http://www.scalasca.org/) or [TAU](http://www.cs.uoregon.edu/research/tau/news.php), and commercial tools like [Vampir](https://www.vampir.eu/) or [Intel Trace Analyzer](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-trace-analyzer).

Comment: Scalasca and Tau seem to be a good choice for my problem. Thank you